# Field ordonnanceService in ...OrdonnanceController required a bean of type 'OrdonnanceService' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I am new to Spring Boot and I'm getting the following error when writing a file upload API:

```
    > 2020-05-31 12:07:30.713  INFO 22808 --- [           main]
    > o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with
    > port(s): 8080 (http) 2020-05-31 12:07:30.725  INFO 22808 --- [        
    > main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service
    > [Tomcat] 2020-05-31 12:07:30.725  INFO 22808 --- [           main]
    > org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine:
    > [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27] 2020-05-31 12:07:30.908  INFO 22808 --- [      
    > main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring
    > embedded WebApplicationContext 2020-05-31 12:07:30.908  INFO 22808 ---
    > [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root
    > WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3202 ms 2020-05-31
    > 12:07:30.978  WARN 22808 --- [           main]
    > ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
    > during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
    > org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
    > Error creating bean with name 'ordonnanceController': Unsatisfied
    > dependency expressed through field 'ordonnanceService'; nested
    > exception is
    > org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
    > qualifying bean of type 'pfa.ordodistance.services.OrdonnanceService'
    > available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
    > candidate. Dependency annotations:
    > {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    > 2020-05-31 12:07:30.982  INFO 22808 --- [           main]
    > o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
    > 2020-05-31 12:07:31.013  INFO 22808 --- [           main]
    > ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
    > 
    > Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
    > re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2020-05-31 12:07:31.153
    > ERROR 22808 --- [           main]
    > o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 
    > 
    > *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
    > ***************************
    > 
    > Description:
    > 
    > Field ordonnanceService in
    > pfa.ordodistance.controllers.OrdonnanceController required a bean of
    > type 'pfa.ordodistance.services.OrdonnanceService' that could not be
    > found.
    > 
    > The injection point has the following annotations:
    >   - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
    > 
    > 
    > Action:
    > 
    > Consider defining a bean of type
    > 'pfa.ordodistance.services.OrdonnanceService' in your configuration.
```

This is my class Service:

```java
@Service
public class OrdonnanceService {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private OrdonnanceRepository ordonnanceRepository;

    //Save new ordonnance
    public void save(Ordonnance ord) {
        ordonnanceRepository.save(ord);
    }
}
```

Controller :

```java
@Controller
@ComponentScan("pfa.ordodistance.controllers")
public class OrdonnanceController {

    @Autowired(required = true) 
    private OrdonnanceService ordonnanceService;

    @PostMapping("prescriptionPage")
    public String addNew(Ordonnance ord) {
        ordonnanceService.save(ord);
        return "redirect:/prescriptionPage";
    }
}
```

Repository:

```java
@Repository
public interface OrdonnanceRepository extends JpaRepository<Ordonnance, Integer> {
}
```

Model :

```java
@Entity
public class Ordonnance {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    private Date dateO;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="medecinid", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Medecin medecin;
    private Integer medecinid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="patientid", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Patient patient;
    private Integer patientid;

    public Ordonnance() {
    }

    public Ordonnance(int id, Date dateO, Medecin medecin, Integer medecinid, Patient patient, Integer patientid) {
        this.id = id;
        this.dateO = dateO;
        this.medecin = medecin;
        this.medecinid = medecinid;
        this.patient = patient;
        this.patientid = patientid;
    }
     //getters & setters
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the `OrdonnanceService` cannot be registered as a spring bean and hence no `OrdonnanceService` can be auto-wired into `OrdonnanceController` and hence resulting this error.

One thing to check is to make sure  `@ComponentScan` covers all the required classes that should be registered as spring beans.

In your case , as you set the `@ComponentScan` as :

```java
@ComponentScan("pfa.ordodistance.controllers")
```

It will only scan and register spring beans coming for this and its sub-packages. So if `OrdonnanceService` is in the package of `pfa.ordodistance.service` , it will not be scanned.

One simply try is to change it to :

```java
@ComponentScan("pfa.ordodistance")
```

On the other hands , if you follow the best practise as suggested in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-locating-the-main-class) which put the main application class (i.e class that annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`) to the root package above all packages  , you do not need to manually configure `@ComponentScan` as it will scan for every classes under this root package. See the example layout in the above link for I mean.

Comment: Tkanks a lot , actually my error was that I add this annotation @ComponentScan({ "pfa.ordodistance.controllers, com.ordodistance.models, com.controller.repositories, com.controller.services"}) in my main class